# sed command to remove some text

Tags: bash, shell, sed

There are dozens and dozens of posts in a lot of forums dealing with the command "sed".
Unfortunately, no one tutorial, no one post solved my very basic problem, I hope I will finally find a solution here :)

Here it is, I have hundreds of lines like this one :

```
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] ([TABLE_ONE_ID], [TABLE_ONE_MNEMO], [TABLE_ONE_DESC], [AUTO_ANALYSIS], [SCOPE_LEVEL], [IN_ABV], [TABLE_ONE_ORDER], [REPORT_ETE]) VALUES (204, N'PERFO TEST', N'PERFO TEST', N'N', 1, 0, 999, N'70')
```

I just want to remove the string 'dbo' and the N prefix, so I would like to replace :

```
204, N'PERFO TEST', N'PERFO TEST', N'N', 1, 0, 999, N'70'
```

by :

```
204, 'PERFO TEST', 'PERFO TEST', 'N', 1, 0, 999, '70'
```

For the 'dbo' string, I found a solution but I  don't like it because if there is another d, another b or another o in the text they also will be removed.

```
sed -i 's/[dbo]//g' file
```

Now, if I follow these instructions, according to a tutorial (http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html), it should work but it doesn't :

```
sed -i 's/dbo//g' file
```

It just... doesn't do anything ! So if you have a better solution, it would be great !

Now, for the N prefix, I just want to delete all the letters N that are after the coma, just like in the example above. If you have the solution, please do not hesitate to share it, I tried a looooot of different syntaxes and I just could delete all the N of the file haha :)

Thank you for your time !

Comment: If `sed -i 's/dbo//g' file` doesn't do anything, then that means the characters `dbo` aren't present anywhere in the file. We need a full example of a real line from the file.

Comment: In the first line of my post (INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] etc...) after the command sed -i 's/dbo//g' file, the [dbo] is still there, in the file. Anything changed and I do not understand why. @KevinMGranger

Comment: I just tried it on my machine and ti worked perfectly fine. Are you sure you're running it on the right file, and viewing the right one after?

Comment: @KevinMGranger as I said in another comment below, I think it is because I didn't do a dos2unix on the file before. Maybe it's the problem

Comment: Ok, that was the problem ! After the dos2unix command, it now works perfectly. Sorry I had to think about it before. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I just tried the same command on the same file after using unix2dos, and it still worked. It's doubtful that that was the issue.

Comment: Hum... yes I agree. I swear that I tried the same command before and after the dos2unix and it worked only after... It's weird

Comment: Try removing the `-i`. Some seds (e.g. AIX) require a backup file name after the `-i` so MAYBE your sed is treating some/all of your script as a backup file name since it follows `-i`. Btw `[dbo]` is a character list inside a bracket expression and it means "any of the characters b, d, or o", it does NOT mean "the string [dbo]" or anything else you might have intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one `sed 's/dbo//g' | sed 's/, N/, /g'`:

```
➜  ~ echo "INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] ([TABLE_ONE_ID], [TABLE_ONE_MNEMO], [TABLE_ONE_DESC], [AUTO_ANALYSIS], [SCOPE_LEVEL], [IN_ABV], [TABLE_ONE_ORDER], [REPORT_ETE]) VALUES (204, N'PERFO TEST', N'PERFO TEST', N'N', 1, 0, 999, N'70')" | sed 's/dbo//g' | sed 's/, N/, /g'
```

Comment: you can do this in one sed invocation `sed 's/dbo//g;s/,  *N/, /g'`

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried your solutions, but, I don't understand... it should work and the [dbo] and the ", N" are still here ! I just remind that the file I'm using comes from Windows and I am on Linux, should I try a dos2unix before ? @jm666

Comment: Thank you for the syntax ! The command works perfectly. I had to do a dos2unix before so it works now ;) Yes @jm666 that's what I thought, nevertheless, after the dos2unix the command worked and not before. I imported a file.sql from Windows on a virtual RHEL machine. It's my first time doing that so I don't know if it really was the problem.

Comment: This will also remove `N`s from within the strings, if the strings contain also a coma and a space.

Comment: Yes @ceving you're right ! What would be the solution to delete only these N prefixes ? Do you think `sed 's/, *N\'/, \'/g'` could work ?